# ¿Cómo implementar JSON Web Token?

Tags: java, json, jwt, tokens, tapestry

- Se tiene un API REST con SpringBoot como Back end y la autenticación está por BASIC sobre HTTPS (ya se, debería ser también por token pero ya está así).
- Se tiene un Front End con tapestry que se comunica con el back end.
- Se tiene una aplicación principal que usa Struts y EJBs 3, a esta aplicación es a la que los usuarios ingresan. Esta aplicación se quiere ir migrando paulatinamente desarrollando los nuevos requerimientos sobre los dos esquemas arriba descritos (api rest y tapestry).

La idea es que desde la aplicación principal que tiene Struts y EJB's ya existe un login y se me ocurre que los nuevos desarrollos embeberlos con un iframe, por lo tanto la idea sería que desde la aplicación principal generar y firmar el token con un periodo de expiración de unos 20 minutos y enviarlo en la URL que se pasa al iframe:

```
iframe src="https://misitio.com?jwt=23878913hvasdasd.fss2323423423dfsdf.sdfsdfsertet
```

Por lo tanto, el nuevo front end de tapestry se encargaría de validar el token.

Las preguntas obligatorias:

¿Es buena idea hacerlo de esta forma? ¿De qué otra manera se puede hacer? ¿Es inseguro usar el iframe y pasarle ahí el JSON Web Token?

Yo pienso que al usar la llave privada no importa que el token esté expuesto y adicional al tiempo de expiración de 20 minutos.

Comment: Hola @user5660423. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Las preguntas que estás realizando buscan respuestas basadas en opiniones, algo que se busca evitar en el sitio. ¿Se te ocurre cómo poder orientar la pregunta para llevarla a algo más concreto? Si es así, sería genial si pudieses [edit] la pregunta buscando respuestas únicas.

Answer (score 1):

@Mariano tiene razón en cuanto a que muchas respuestas se basarán en la opinión  de cada usuario, así que responderé a la pregunta más concreta de tu post.

> ¿Es inseguro usar el iframe y pasarle ahi el JSON Web Token?

En general, **es inseguro** pasar credenciales como parámetros en la URL (método GET).

Aunque tu petición sea HTTPS, la URL con total seguridad será incluida en los ficheros de trazas (logs) de todos los servidores/proxy/etc. por los que pase.

En su lugar, utiliza POST y HTTPS para transferir está información.